# Como usar getche() com do-while em C?

Tags: c, do-while

Eu tenho a seguinte variável :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

char op;
```

E estou pedindo para o usuário entrar com um caractere :

```
printf("\nDeseja realizar novo teste (s/n) ?");
op = getche();
```

Caso o usuário digitar `s` o seguinte código irá aparecer :

```
    printf("\nDigite um número para o dividendo : \n");
    scanf("%d", &dividendo);
    printf("\nDigite um número para o divisor : \n");
    scanf("%d", &divisor);
```

E caso o usuário digite `n`, o programa sai, mas caso digite qualquer outro caractere, ele aparece, a mesma mensagem pedindo para para realizar novo teste.

**Código :**

```
do {

printf("\nDeseja realizar novo teste (s/n) ?");
op = getche();

}while(getche() != 's' || getche != 'n');
```

Ele continua rodando o `do-while`, mesmo se eu colocar os caracteres `s` ou `n`, como posso fazer funcionar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra ler um caractere, basta usar `scanf` mesmo.

```
char ch;
scanf(" %c", &ch);
printf("%c", ch);
```

Repare que no `scanf` tem um espaço ants do `%c`. Isso serve pra indicar que a função ignore todos os espaços em branco adicionais que vem do teclado e leia apenas o caractere. E evite usar `getche`, eu acho que essa função não é padrão do C.

Edit:

```
char op;
while (1) {

    printf("\nDeseja realizar novo teste (s/n) ?");
    op = getche();

    if (op == 's' || op == 'n') {
        printf("\n\nVc escolheu '%c'", op);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu prefiro usar scanf também, mas é um exercício da Faculdade, e pede claramente para usar getche, mesmo que eu não queira usar. E está só dando problemas com o getche().

Comment: Tente usar um loop infinito e verificar o caractere com `if`. Teste aqui com o Visual Studio 2015 e funcionou. Atualizei o código.

Comment: Sim, funcionou. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o problema está no fato de você estar usando a função na condição, quando na verdade você teria que usar a variável na condição do do-while. Tente dessa forma e veja o que acontece:

```
do {

printf("\nDeseja realizar novo teste (s/n) ?");
op = getche();

}while(op != 's' || op != 'n');
```

Comment: Também não funcionou, ele fica perguntando 3 vezes a mesma coisa, e não da output correto. Ele não consegue pegar o sim ou não, ou outro caractere, e fica um loop infinito.

Comment: @Mondial, você fez o import da biblioteca conio? Se não, coloca no cabeçalho do script: #include <conio.h>

Comment: Sim, eu fiz o import da biblioteca conio.

Comment: Você ajudou também, muito obrigado.